# Finding partial derivatives from a given function

Tags: calculus, self-learning, partial-derivative

[image]

For i), is the answer $df/du = (a)df/dx + (2cu)df/dy, df/dv = (b)df/dx + (2dv)df/dy$

For ii), is the answer  $d^2 f/du^2 = (a^2) d^2 f/dx^2 + (4acu) d^2 f/dxdy + (4c^2 u^2) d^2 f/dy^2$ ,

$d^2 f/dv^2 = (b^2) d^2 f/dx^2 + (4bdv) d^2 f/dxdy + (4d^2 v^2) d^2 f/dy^2$

Comment: Have you heard of _the chain rule_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x(u,v)=au+bv$ $\quad$ $y(u,v)=cu^2+dv^2$

So $\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial u}=a$ and $\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial v}=b$

and  $\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial u}=2cu$ and $\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial v}=2dv$

Now use the chain rule :

(i)

$\therefore \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u}=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial u}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial u}=a\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}+2cu\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$.

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v}=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial v}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial v}=b\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}+2du\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$.

From here I think you can proceed. For further help with partial derivatives check [this](http://jacobi.math.wvu.edu/~hjlai/Teaching/Tip-Pdf/Tip3-27.pdf) out !!